# Change of master server IP in a Jenkins master child cluster

Tags: windows, jenkins, devops

We have a Jenkins cluster running with master node and 6 child nodes(4 windows child nodes, 2 Linux child nodes).
Recently the IP of the master node has changed due to network updates.
The Linux child node are successful in connecting with the master node whereas the windows child nodes are not able to connect.
The client jar file after change of master node IP for windows fails to connect with the to master node from child node.
Does anyone know how to configure the system when Jenkins master node IP has changed with windows child nodes?
Jenkins version is 2.9

Tried changing configs for windows child nodes.
Generated Client JAR files after change of master node IP.

Comment: Have you tried to test connectivity using telnet or something similar? It could be a network/firewall problem, not a Jenkins problem

Comment: Maybe remove the nodes and add them again?

Comment: @Atxulo. The windows nodes are working under VYOS router yes. I will look into this on Monday and revert.

Comment: @MB I did think about adding new nodes with both windows and Linux. I will definitely try this. Thanks